# "amounts of data" vs. "amount of data"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I have a question about the following sentence:

> Analyzed large amounts of data from multiple sources using descriptive and inferential statistics.

Is *amounts* right here or do I have to write *amount*?

In parallel, is using *data sets* and *datasets* indifferent? I understand that *data sets* is the correct form, but nowadays, especially in the technical field, *datasets* is commonly used. It's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A noun may be uncountable in some circumstance, yet countable in others.

- There are many fish in the lake. [uncountable]
- Perch and bass are fishes found there. [countable, because there are different *types* of fish]
- The water in Rio Negro* is dark from humic acid and tannins. [uncountable]
- The Meeting of Waters (Encontro das Águas) is the confluence of Rio Negro and Amazon. [countable, because these are two different sources]

Because there are multiple data sources, I'd use the plural, *amounts*. If it were one humongous data set, e.g., the census data for India, then I'd use *amount*.